# Adding css global variables using javascript

Tags: css, css-variables

First of all if you read this question and I did have any misunderstandings of how css works please let me know

I'm trying to add some global variables to my stylesheets and I want to do it with javascript (I thought there may be a way to use global variables without importing a css file containing those variables in each css file I'm creating):

```
let cssContent = `:root{ --mainColor:"#333";}
```

First I tried to create a new stylesheet file and put `cssContent` in there:

```
var blob = new Blob([cssContent]);
var url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);

var cssElement = document.createElement('link');
cssElement.setAttribute('rel', 'stylesheet');
cssElement.setAttribute('type', 'text/css');
cssElement.setAttribute('href', url);
```

Then to add this stylesheet to head, first I removed all exsisting stylesheets, add `cssElement` and then all the other removed stylesheets so the `cssElement` be the first stylesheet in head element.

```
var cssElements = Array.from(document.head.getElementsByTagName('link'))
                       .filter(link => link.getAttribute('rel') == 'stylesheet');
if (cssElements && cssElements.length > 0) {
       cssElements.forEach(cssEl => {
         document.head.removeChild(cssEl)
       });
```

The behavior of removing and adding stylesheets works fine
[image]
[image]
[image]

But the `:root` element goes after the defined rule for `body` and does not apply:

[image]

Then I tried to add this variables to each css file instead of creating new one:

```
 for (let index = 0; index < document.styleSheets.length; index++) {
        document.styleSheets[index].insertRule(cssContent, 0);
      }
```

Again same thing happened to previous approach, happens here too:

[image]

At last I tried to add this variables to each rule, but I couldn't find an approach

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Remove the quotes from around #333

Comment: @AHaworth wow! how silly I am, I did remove the quote and It works fine now thanks

Answer (score 1):

you can use these three:

```
document.documentElement.style.setProperty("--mainColor", "#333");
```

[Element.setAttribute()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute)

### OR

```
document.documentElement.style.cssText = "--mainColor: #333";
```

[Document.documentElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/documentElement)

### OR

```
document.documentElement.setAttribute("style", "--mainColor: #333");
```

[CSSStyleDeclaration.setProperty()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleDeclaration/setProperty)